# How to make a function save modifications to a struct input in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, io

I have 2 functions in my file, one for input of info in a struct('vpis()') and one for printing out contents of it('izpis()'). The input function does not save the information I enter. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum TIP_NASLOVA {
    STALNI,
    ZACASNI
};

struct Naslov {
    string ulica;
    string posta;
    int postna_stevilka;
    TIP_NASLOVA tip;
};

struct Oseba {
    string ime;
    string priimek;
    int starost;
    Naslov naslov;
};

void izpis(Oseba oseba) {
    cout << "IZPIS VNOSA" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Ime: " << oseba.ime << endl;
    cout << "Priimek: " << oseba.priimek << endl;
    cout << "Starost: " << oseba.starost << endl;
    cout << "Tip Naslova: " << oseba.naslov.tip << endl;
    cout << "Posta: " << oseba.naslov.postna_stevilka << " " << oseba.naslov.posta << endl;
    cout << "Naslov: " << oseba.naslov.ulica << endl;
}

void vpis(Oseba oseba) {
    int tip;
    cout << "VPIS PODATKOV NOVEGA VNOSA" << endl << endl;
    cout << endl << "VPISI IME: ";
    cin >> oseba.ime;
    cout << endl << "VPISI PRIIMEK: ";
    cin >> oseba.priimek;
    cout << endl << "VPISI STAROST: ";
    cin >> oseba.starost;
    cout << endl << "VPISI TIP NASLOVA ( 1-STALNI / 2-ZACASNI ): ";
    cin >> tip;

    switch (tip){
        case 1:
            oseba.naslov.tip = STALNI;
            break;
        case 2:
            oseba.naslov.tip = ZACASNI;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Napaka! Izbrali ste napacen tip naslova. " <<endl;
            break;
    }

    cout << endl << "VPISI POSTNO STEVILKO: ";
    cin >> oseba.naslov.postna_stevilka;
    cout << endl << "VPISI POSTO: ";
    cin >> oseba.naslov.posta;
    cout << endl << "VPISI NASLOV (FORMAT:'TrgGeneralaMaistra1'): ";
    cin >> oseba.naslov.ulica;
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    Oseba oseba;
    int x;
    cout << "VPIS IN IZPIS OSEBNIH PODATKOV" << endl << endl;
    for (;;) {
        cout << "Dolocite zahtevano operacijo (1-VPIS, 2-IZPIS): ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << endl << endl;
        switch (x){
        case 1:
            vpis(oseba);
            break;
        case 2:
            izpis(oseba);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Izbrali niste nobene operacije!" << endl << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to pass the object by reference if you want to make changes to it :)

change `void vpis(Oseba oseba) {`

to `void vpis(Oseba& oseba) {`

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a fast reply. That was exactly what I was looking for. I've spent about 2 hours staring at the screen and trying to google this. I kept trying to link it when I called the function. Like this:

     vpis(Oseba &oseba);

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your struct to each function **by value**, so each function receives a *copy* of the struct, and as such any changes you make are to the copy, not the original.  Change your functions to pass the struct **by reference** instead.

```
void izpis(const Oseba &oseba)
```

```
void vpis(Oseba &oseba)
```